# How to accept only predefined values in an Angular @Input

Tags: angular, typescript, parameters, enums

My problem here is that I receive a string value in a as a parameter to a component, but I want to limit the values that can be used as a parameter, just like an `enum`

I use

```
@Input() type: string = '';
```

But the in the component, everything can be introduced to the `type` property and I need to limit that to just 3 options, as I said before, like an `Enum`

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "limit", and at what point you expect the warning/error to be throw. An easy solution is just to check the values on your component and throw an exception if they aren't valid. If you're looking for a compile time solution then at the very least you need angular to be converting your templates to scripts at compile time (i.e. AOT) - in that case simply typing the input value may work - i.e. use Typescript to restrict the type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an [**Enum**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) and set the type of your `input` to the enum. Your value will be passed if it is one of the values in enum, otherwise it will be `undefined`

```
enum MyEnum {
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}

@Input() type: MyEnum;
```

Comment: I didn't find this to be true in angular 7. I implemented this, but I am still able to pass in any string outside the MyEnum values. Instead of undefined, the `type` variable is populated with the random string that was passed in...

Comment: Just found this article. It helped clear things up. https://angularfirst.com/typescript-string-enums/

Answer (score 13):

try this:

```
@Input() type: 'acceptable1' | 'acceptable2' | 'acceptable3';
```

This uses the typescript union type allowing any of the listed types. a or b or c etc

or use a [TS enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)