# How to restrict input property values in an Angular custom input control?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have a custom Angular 4 component and want to restrict an input property to valid TypeScript enum values.  I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245304/how-to-accept-only-predefined-values-in-an-angular-input) which seems identical, but I can't seem to get the accepted answer to work as I expected it to work.

Here's my component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

enum MyEnum {
  ValueInMyEnum,
  One,
  Two,
  Three
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>Prop1 value: {{ prop1 }}</div>
      <div>Prop2 value: {{ prop2 }}</div>
      <div>Prop3 value: {{ prop3 }}</div>
      <div>Prop4 value: {{ prop4 }}</div>
      <div>Prop5 value: {{ prop5 }}</div>
      <div>Prop6 value: {{ prop6 }}</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() prop1: MyEnum;
  @Input() prop2: MyEnum;
  @Input() prop3: string
  @Input() prop4: MyEnum;
  @Input() prop5: MyEnum;
  @Input() prop6: string

}
```

Here's how I'm using my component:

```
<my-component 
      prop1="ValueInMyEnum"
      prop2="ValueNotInMyEnum"
      prop3="Prop3IsJustAStringType"
      [prop4]="ValueInMyEnum"
      [prop5]="ValueNotInMyEnum"
      [prop6]="Prop6IsJustAStringType"
></my-component>
```

I would like to be able to supply a value that's in the enum and be able to use its value as the `MyEnum` type in my component code, but everything seems to just be undefined. How can I correctly supply an enum value into my component?

Here's a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/kmUZYgemCpsc9dIg0HGU?p=preview) to help demo this.

Comment: Your case is not completely identical. True, you use defined @Input types, but only in the child. In the parent component neither of <my-component> attributes are defined or initialised in the parent. For the first three you just pass strings so they are rendered as is, in three others the attribute values are not recognized by the child because they don't exist in parent

Comment: I don't understand what this means. I only have one component, `my-component`, and I am trying to assign and use the propX properties that are defined on that component. Why would I ever want to define my propX properties in the parent `my-app` component?

Comment: You have at least two components my-app and my-component. @Input is the link between two components so it has to have a value defined in the parent to be transmitted to the child. Read here https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction

Comment: I understand what you mean, I think. You're saying I actually need to have an enum value in my parent before I can pass it to the my-component child.  Is that a correct interpretation of what you're saying?

Comment: Maybe my question is sort of useless then, because I really want to just pass the text in (like `prop1="One"`) and have it translated into an enum on the child side. I basically just want to enforce an enumerated list of legal string values to the user of my-component.  I don't really want to require the user to import the enum and use it as a type.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.ts import MyEnum and use a auxiliar variable

```
....
import { MyComponent,MyEnum } from './my-component';
....
export class App {
    IEnum=MyEnum; //<--add the variable
    constructor() {...}
```

then you can write

```
<my-component [prop4]="IEnum.ValueInMyEnum"></my-component>
```